# Segmentation fault on strlen(char*) but char* IS terminated

Tags: c, char, segmentation-fault

I've got a very very simple function which simply converts a char to a char* which represents the binary value of the char with 0's and 1's as chars.

```
char* stringToBin(char symbol) {
    int pos = 0;
    int value = (int) symbol;
    int rest;

    char* result = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * 9);

    while(value > 0) {
            if(value % 2 == 0) {
                    result[7-pos] = '0';
            }
            else {
                    result[7-pos] = '1';
            }
            pos++;
            value = value / 2;
    }

    while(pos < 8) {
            result[7-pos] = '0';
            pos++;
    }

    result[8] = '\0';

    puts(result);
    puts(strlen(result));

    return result;
}
```

My problem is I can't print the length of the char*. Printing the whole char* works perfect but not calculating the size. I alway get a segmentation fault. I think the problem is pretty simple but I did not get it right now. So please give me the missing hint ;)

Comment: Please construct a complete [SSCCE test-case](http://sscce.org), including the input that causes the problem.

Comment: Standard hint: compile with all warnings & debugging info (e.g. `gcc -Wall -g` on Linux) and use the debugger (e.g. `gdb`)

Comment: Is value perhaps negative?

Comment: Neither. `puts(strlen(result));` is the problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is not with the NUL-termination of your string, that's fine. Instead,

```
puts(strlen(result));
```

is wrong. `puts()` expects a C string, and you're giving it a `size_t`. Write instead:

```
printf("%zu\n", strlen(result));
```

(This assumes that the C99 format specifier `%zu` for `size_t` is available. If it isn't, then use:

```
printf("%u\n", (unsigned)strlen(result));
```

instead.)